# Why use a cube as a reference volume in the kinetic theory of gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

In basic kinetic theory we often use cubes. For example, the derivation of the ideal gas law is done with a cubical volume. Is a cube necessary for it to work? If not, wouldn't a sphere be more symmetric and thus simpler?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Depends on the level of the presentation and the way you intend to balance hand-waving against grotty equations.

Comment: Write out the derivation in (x,y,z). Write out the derivation in (r,$\Theta$,$\psi$). Compare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a cube is an extension of the choice of coordinates used in the mathematical modeling.  $dV=dxdydz$  is a small cube after all.  [$dV$  is more](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TISphericalCoords.aspx) complicated in radial coordinates